# Lattice in pocketsphinx android

Tags: android, android-ndk, sphinx

I need to get the word lattice DAG in pocketsphinx android. Is it possible?

And if it is, what functions do i have to wrap?
I think I will have to wrap following in pocketsphinx.h:

```
/**
 * Get word lattice.
 *
 * There isn't much you can do with this so far, a public API will
 * appear in the future.
 *
 * @param ps Decoder.
 * @return Word lattice object containing all hypotheses so far.  NULL
 *         if no hypotheses are available.  This pointer is owned by
 *         the decoder and you should not attempt to free it manually.
 *         It is only valid until the next utterance, unless you use
 *         ps_lattice_retain() to retain it.
 */
POCKETSPHINX_EXPORT
ps_lattice_t *ps_get_lattice(ps_decoder_t *ps);

/**
 * Get an iterator over the word segmentation for the best hypothesis.
 *
 * @param ps Decoder.
 * @param out_best_score Output: path score corresponding to hypothesis.
 * @return Iterator over the best hypothesis at this point in
 *         decoding.  NULL if no hypothesis is available.
 */
POCKETSPHINX_EXPORT
ps_seg_t *ps_seg_iter(ps_decoder_t *ps, int32 *out_best_score);

/**
 * Get the next segment in a word segmentation.
 *
 * @param seg Segment iterator.
 * @return Updated iterator with the next segment.  NULL at end of
 *         utterance (the iterator will be freed in this case).
 */
POCKETSPHINX_EXPORT
ps_seg_t *ps_seg_next(ps_seg_t *seg);

/**
 * Get word string from a segmentation iterator.
 *
 * @param seg Segment iterator.
 * @return Read-only string giving string name of this segment.  This
 * is only valid until the next call to ps_seg_next().
 */
   POCKETSPHINX_EXPORT
   char const *ps_seg_word(ps_seg_t *seg);
```

Please correct me if i am wrong?

Comment: Did you figure this out?